# Is method semantically equivalent to function in Scala 3?

Tags: scala, semantics, scala-3

In Scala 2 [as explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529184/difference-between-method-and-function-in-scala) we had a **Function Type** that was implementing trait `FunctionX` and **Method Type** that was a **non-value** type. We could transform a method to **Method Value** which was an instance of **Function Type** like this:

```scala
class Sample {
  def method(x:Int) = x+1
  val methodValue = method _
}
```

Now in Scala 3, we can leave the underscore so it looks more like this:

```scala
class Sample:
  def method(x:Int) = x+1
  val methodValue = method
```

Isn't the **equality** sign suggesting semantic equivalence of method and function value in `val methodValue = method`? Also in Scala 2 I couldn't use any methods (at least in Scastie with Scala version 2.13.5) on created method like apply but in Scala 3 I can do that suggesting that methods in Scala 3 are regular objects:

```scala
scala> val s = Sample()                                                                                                      
val s: Sample = Sample@793c2cde

scala> s.method                                                                                                              
val res13: Int => Int = Lambda$1530/856511870@ab595e8

scala> s.methodValue
val res14: Int => Int = Sample$$Lambda$1422/1191732945@1bbbede1

scala> s.method.                                                                                                             
!=             andThen        compose        finalize       isInstanceOf   notifyAll      →
##             apply          ensuring       formatted      ne             synchronized
->             asInstanceOf   eq             getClass       nn             toString
==             clone          equals         hashCode       notify         wait
```

So is Scala 3 functions and methods the same or very similar objects or at least the difference has been significantly reduced?

Comment: Follow up could be if they are similar objects why in jvm bytecode they implemented so different: one is `public int method(int);` and the other is `public scala.Function1<java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object> methodValue();`

Comment: No, they are not the same, **functions** are still values, **methods** are still not. And methods are probably still more efficient but probably almost nobody should care about that. - **Scala 3** just did an amazing job in reducing their differences and improving their ergnomics.

Answer (score 3):

> Isn't the equality sign suggesting semantic equivalence of method and
> function value in val methodValue = method?

The key concept to understand is **eta expansion** which converts methods into functions. Scala 3 has [automated](https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/changed-features/eta-expansion.html) this process so

> The syntax `m _` is no longer needed and will be deprecated in the
> future.

Hence methods and functions are not the same, however Scala 3 tries to transparently convert between them so programmers do not have to worry about the distinction.

Comment: so I can use for example `s.method.apply(1)` (and REPL is suggesting all these function value methods like `apply`) because method will be eta expanded to the function value before `apply` is executed?

Comment: @karolwołonciej Correct. [A reference to unapplied method](https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/issues/2570#issuecomment-306202339) is always eta expanded if method has one or more parameters.